# Having trouble using expect() in protractor, want to get the first child's text and compare it to a string

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to get the element's child's text and test if it equals a user input string.

Have tried the code below, which has resulted in the same error msg

```
await expect(element(by.className('tlid-translation translation').isDisplayed()).to.equal(true)
```

as well as throwing in some random .eventually or checking for element.all, but none of these seem to help.

Page:

```
var CalculatorPage = function() {

    var expect = require('chai').expect;

  this.get = function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('https://translate.google.com/', 50000);
  };

  this.checkTrans = async(stringg) => {
       await expect(element(by.className('tlid-translation translation').get(0).getText()).to.equal(stringg)
    }


};

module.exports = CalculatorPage;
```

Steps:

```
var chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var expect = chai.expect;

var CalculatorSteps = function() {

  var TranslatePage = require("../pages/translate_page.js");


  this.World = function MyWorld() {
    this.page = new TranslatePage();
  };

  this.When('I see $stringg as translated', async function end(stringg) {
      await this.page.checkTrans(stringg)
    })

};

module.exports = CalculatorSteps;
```

The erro msg:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Specific:**

The problem is with the parentheses in your code. Also, avoid deprecated methods

*Change:*

```
await expect(element(by.className('tlid-translation translation').isDisplayed()).to.equal(true)
```

to

```
await expect(element(by.css('tlid-translation translation:nth-child(1)')).getText()).toBe(stringg);
```

*Change:*

```
await expect(element(by.className('tlid-translation translation').isDisplayed()).to.equal(true)
```

to

```
await expect(element(by.className('tlid-translation translation')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

**In General:**

- `expect()` needs a promise. Most of the protractor API deals with
  Promises given it has to deal with browser asynchronous nature. Make
  sure `expect()` is getting a promise
- `element()` needs a Locator for ex. `by.css('div')`. Make sure thats
  the case.
- Methods on `element(Locator)` will always return a protractor
  Promise. Make sure the code handles it that way.
- I would prefer CSS selector to get a child element rather than using
  get all elements and then get an element from that list. That way its
  a bit more performant and we dont need API to handle.

Hope that helps..